# MySQL query to pick specific DATETIME values?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Right now I have a MySQL table with one column called "date_time" that simply lists different DATETIME values (e.g. "2010-11-30 12:55:00"). Is it possible for me to construct a query that directly:

- Selects DATETIME values where the *month* is the current month?
- Selects DATETIME values where the *days* aren't passed days (e.g. tomorrow and until the end of the month?

An abstract query in my mind would look like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM meetings WHERE uid = " . $_SESSION['uid'] . "AND the DATETIME month is active month AND the DATETIME day is bigger than the active day"
```

Is this functionality possible in MySQL (did some searching but didn't find anything helpful), or will I have to use PHP functions later to filter this stuff out? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: what's wrong with using `WHERE date_time<NOW()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

`$query = "SELECT * FROM meetings WHERE uid = " . $_SESSION['uid'] . "WHERE EXTRACT(month from now()) = extract(month from date_time) AND EXTRACT(day from now()) < extract(day from date_time)`

Answer (score 5):

MySQL has a ton of [date formatting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) functions that would solve this for you:

Select by specific month...

```
SELECT ... WHERE MONTH(date_time) = MONTH(now());
```

Select by non-passed days:

```
SELECT ... WHERE DAY(date_time) > DAY(now());
```

Of course, these sorts of queries will pick out the same month/days in ANY records from ANY years. If you want to restrict to particular chunks of time, then you'll have to add more clauses.

Comment: I really need to improve my search skills, since I did not find that page. Many thanks for bringing this to my attention!